# Boys And Girls Problem. How to prove that the algorithm is correct?

Tags: algorithm-analysis, proof-techniques, correctness-proof

Given that, there are 10 children standing in a circle, 8 of them stand next to a boy, and 4 of them stand next to a girl.
If 7 boys and 3 girls stand in the following order: GBGBGBBBBB, then 8 children stand next to a boy:

(**G** -> B **G** -> B **G** -> **B** -> **B** -> **B** -> **B** -><- **B**)

and 3 children stand next to a girl:

(-> G **B** -> G **B** -> G B B B B **B** ->)

Now, given that, there are **n** children standing in a circle, **x** of them stand next to a boy, and **y** of them stand next to a girl.
Where n >= 2 and 0 <= x, y <= n;
If there is a solution, we print the order of boys and girls in the format similar to: BGBGGG, where B stands for "boy" and G stands for "girl", otherwise, we print "Impossible".
Here is the pseudo-code:

```
sortBoysAndGirls(n, x, y) {
    if (n == 2 and x == 1 and y == 1) {
        print "BG"
        return
    }

    if (x == y or ((x - 1) + (y - 1)) != n) {
        print "Impossible"
        return
    }

    result = ""
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (x > 1) {
            result = result + "B"
            --x
        }
        if (y > 1) {
            result = result + "G"
            --y
        }
    }

    print result
    return
}
```

Implementing and testing the algorithm (using tester/checker) above showed, that it works in concrete situations, but now i need to prove that it works generally.
Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? We do not want to just hand you the solution; we want you to gain understanding. However, as it is we do not know what your underlying problem is, so we can not begin to help. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/1284/98) for tips on asking questions about exercise problems. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Do you want the technique to prove that algorithm works or the algorithm itself or get your algorithm checked? Not all of above are on-topic here.

Comment: You correctly pointed out, i checked the algorithm in concrete situations, but now I need a technique to prove the algorithm works. @Evil